# FiboSearch plugin Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, plugins

Would you please help me adding a Scroll of a result while I am using Fibosearch plugin woocommerce ?

I tried to get the ID of the item that is a wrapper for the product list but I could not.

I'll be very grateful if you learn me how to do it.